# T-SQL grouping values on multiple columns and return row values as columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset which returns a number of row, 2 columns RoomType and FaultTypeName should be grouped but those 2 columns also have 1 'Result' column. Because of the 'Result' column the grouping will fail. So to make it clearer, the result set looks as follows:

[image]

The FaultTypeName are always the same three values 'Methode (M)', 'Periodiek (P)' or Vuil (V). These values should be returned as new columns with respectively their result values. So above resultset should be returned as following:

[image]

I already tried to do something with the rownumber (hence the rn column) but this didn't quite work out:

```
select 
       ...
from(
  select MeasurementId, RoomType, FaultTypeName, Result,
    row_number() over(partition by RoomType order by RoomType, FaultTypeName) rn
  from vwReportData
  where measurementid = 1382596
)sub
```

There is a possibility that only 2 (or less) of the 3 columns (Methode, Periodiek and Vuil) are returned instead of all 3 (so less rows), if this is the case, the missing FaultTypeName(s) should still be added as column but with a result of 0.

Any ideas how I can get the right output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from
(
  select MeasurementId, RoomType, FaultTypeName, Result,
    row_number() over(partition by RoomType order by RoomType, FaultTypeName) rn
  from vwReportData
  where measurementid = 1382596
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX(result) for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) PVT
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, I think using a Pivot is not as efficient as I would like. After some more digging, I came up with another answer (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured it out myself:

```
SELECT 
    MeasurementId, 
    RoomType, 
    M = ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN FaultTypeName = 'Methode (M)' THEN Result ELSE NULL END), 0),
    P = ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN FaultTypeName = 'Periodiek (P)' THEN Result ELSE NULL END), 0),
    V = ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN FaultTypeName = 'Vuil (V)' THEN Result ELSE NULL END), 0)
FROM vwReportData
WHERE MeasurementId = 1382596
GROUP BY MeasurementId, RoomType
```